# When should you write a DTD or XML Schema?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I'm writing an application for an embedded device and I'm not seeing anyone bother to write a DTD or XML Schema for XML file that describes the interface layout. I'm trying to clear all the warning from my eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit like asking "when should you write documentation of your interface"?

Answer: when you're concerned with writing software that will have lasting value and provide a solid return on investment rather than with meeting impossible deadlines.